# Congruence arithmetic and a toy NTRU cryptosystem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

This is a doubt from [a textbook](https://g.co/kgs/kCwQce). Suppose $q,f,g\in\mathbb Z$ are positive numbers such that $f<\sqrt{q/2}$, $\sqrt{q/4}<g<\sqrt{q/2}$ and $\gcd(f,q)=1$. We compute the quantity $h\equiv f^{-1}g \mbox{ mod }q$. The text says that we may let $0<h<q$. I believe this is since $f^{-1}$ is a unit and so not a zero divisor.

Next let us take two integers $r,m$ such that $0<m<\sqrt{q/4}; 0<r<\sqrt{q/2}$. Define, $e\equiv rh+m \mbox{ mod }q$. The text says that we may let $0<e<q$. My question is why? Why can't $rh+m$ be a multiple of $q$?

Comment: Maybe if it happens that $e$ is a multiple of $q$, you choose different $r,m$. Could you indicate me the page in the textbook?

Comment: It is  on pg 350.

Comment: Ok, I found it on pg 374 of my version. $m$ is the message so you can't change it, but $r$ is random so you can  change it until you don't have that $e$ is not a multiple of $q$. I know that it is not what is written in the text, but it's what I would do.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks. Thats the conclusion I reached too.